# LINQ Group by and "count-if"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, grouping, linq-to-objects

I want to count all items in a list if a value is true and the count the false values.

I have this:

```
Items.GroupBy(
    i => i.ItemID,
    i => new { isScheduled = i.isScheduled },
    (key, g) => new ItemStatistics()
    {
        ItemID = key,
        ScheduledItems = g.Count(g=>g.isScheduled),
        UnscheduledItems = g.Count(g=> !g.isScheduled)
    }).ToList();
```

this gives me the following compilation error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not
>   a delegate type

as if the it expects a different method overload

when i do this everything seems to be okay...

```
Items.GroupBy(
    i => i.ItemID,
    i => new { isScheduled = i.isScheduled },
    (key, g) => new ItemStatistics()
    {
        ItemID = key,
        ScheduledItems = g.Count(),
        UnscheduledItems = g.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

why is it when i remove the `g=> !g.isScheduled` expression from the count method it accepts it ?

Comment: You missed some `,` between `ScheduledItems = g.Count()` and `UnscheduledItems = g.Count()`?

Comment: @KingKing nope... its with a comma in the code .. i just copied it wrong.. (edited the question code...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it ... ARGH !

when I can use "g" as the variable for my inner lambda expression inside the group becuse it refers to the original group "g". so i changed `g=>g.isScheduled` to`i=>i.isScheduled`

```
Items.GroupBy(
    i => i.ItemID,
    i => new { isScheduled = i.isScheduled },
    (key, g) => new ItemStatistics()
    {
        ItemID = key,
        ScheduledItems = g.Count(i=>i.isScheduled),
        UnscheduledItems = g.Count(i=> !i.isScheduled)
    }).ToList();
```

and now everything is okay

Comment: Why not just select `i=>i.isScheduled`? then you just need `g.Count(i=>i)` and `g.Count(i=>!i)`.

Comment: @KingKing I find `i=>i.isScheduled` more readable than `i=>i`

Comment: If you want readability you can also name it as `g.Count(isScheduled=>isScheduled)` and `g.Count(isScheduled=>!isScheduled)`. I guess the `new {...}` type would be larger than just a `bool`.

Comment: true... thanks... its these one letter lambdas that got stuck in my head :)